# Why did Albus Dumbledore let random people 'Accio' his private books?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort, albus-dumbledore, death-eaters, deathly-hallows

Why did Albus Dumbledore let random people 'Accio' his private books?
In Deathly Hallows, Hermione could do so, and here's the quote:

> ‘I didn’t think there were any books on Horcruxes in the library?’
>
> ‘There weren’t,’ said Hermione, who had turned pink. ‘Dumbledore
> removed them all, but he – he didn’t destroy them.’
>
> Ron sat up straight, wide-eyed. ‘How in the name of Merlin’s pants
> have you managed to get your hands on those Horcrux books?’
>
> ‘It – it wasn’t stealing!’ said Hermione, looking from Harry to Ron
> with a kind of desperation. ‘They were still library books, even if
> Dumbledore had taken them off the shelves. Anyway, if he really didn’t
> want anyone to get at them, I’m sure he would have made it much harder
> to –’
>
> ‘Get to the point!’ said Ron.
>
> ‘Well ... it was easy,’ said Hermione in a small voice. ‘I just did a
> Summoning Charm. You know – accio. And – they zoomed out of
> Dumbledore’s study window right into the girls’ dormitory.’

Did he not believe the Death Eaters and Voldemort (his greatest enemy) would try to summon his private property and learn priceless information that could lead to his defeat?

Comment: Um, "they were still library books, even if Dumbledore had taken them off the shelves." They're not private property.

Comment: @Martha but don't you think that Dumbledore should've added more protections to those books as Death Eaters can steal them, especially Voldemort?

Comment: @KyleV - Voldemort has already read them. Not only that, but he's managed to get hold of higher level books that have taught him how to actually create a Horcrux.

Comment: We don't know that he *didn't* put protections on the books. Dumbledore had been killed by Snape at that point, so the effects of a lot of his spells would have ended.

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/196222/why-didnt-dumbledore-put-the-same-spell-on-the-books-of-the-library-in-restrict/196228#196228

Comment: Hermione summoned the books from one part of Hogwarts to another. This doesn't mean that anyone *outside* the school could do a darn thing with them. And even within the building, it took some, um, unexpected thinking to even try _accio_ on them. V's underlings are not known for such thinking.

Comment: @JPmiaou this doesn't necessarily mean that the Death Eaters were without brains, either. Someone might be able to come up with a plan if they try hard enough.

Answer (score 1):

**Voldemort didn't need the books.**

Voldemort already obtained all of this information long before the events of *Philosopher's Stone* - by that point, he had created several horcruxes, which surely implies that he knew what a horcrux was and how they worked. Therefore, Dumbledore was not trying to prevent Voldemort or his allies from getting their hands on the books. Rather, he was trying to prevent random students from accidentally stumbling onto knowledge that might prove too dangerous at their level of study. As Hermione begins to explain (before Ron cuts her off), Dumbledore probably assumed that anyone who knew enough about the books to summon them was either on the side of good, or at the very least not an immediate threat to themselves or others.

Is this a reasonable assumption? Well, it's debatable. Voldemort himself learned about Horcruxes by talking to Slughorn (though he probably went on to do some independent research as well). Slughorn's dialog suggests that, while horcruxes are not exactly the sort of thing you discuss in polite company, the basic information which he provides is not regarded as a highly sensitive secret. This is also supported by the fact that there were library books for Dumbledore to remove in the first place. In my opinion, it is likely that a sufficiently resourceful witch or wizard would be able to find an alternative source of information, eventually, and so hiding library books was not really going to stop a determined individual, no matter how well you secured them. But at this point in the plot, we don't have "eventually," because Voldemort is already in the process of consolidating his power. Dumbledore presumably reasoned that stymying Harry and company would be a much more severe catastrophe than some unknown non-Voldemort-affiliated actor learning some relatively limited information about horcruxes, which they might be able to obtain elsewhere in any event.